# How can I become an administrator of a Facebook page when the current admin ignores me?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I currently run a society at my university, which has at least two Facebook pages. I would like to gain access to the administrative privileges for the former page because it has more 'likes'. I have tried messaging the administrator of the former Facebook page a number of times, but she has never replied to my Facebook messages. I have also reported the problem to Facebook. They simply replied:

> Your feedback will be used to improve Facebook. Thanks for taking the time to make a report.

Is there any way in which I can gain control over the old page? The pages in question are: [old page](https://www.facebook.com/unasauct) and new: https://www.facebook.com/unasa.blueweek/ {now defunct}.

Comment: I certainly hope not. That would make it far too easy for a bad actor to take over any page that they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't any way for you to do this. If there was a way, then I could take over the page too, and you wouldn't like that.